# Updated Ubuntu, and now, after the boot splashscreen disappears, the screen remains black

Tags: 16.04, updates, graphics, gpu, gpu-driver

I have a NVidia GTX 1050 TI videocard. After we bought this pc, I installed the official GeForce drivers and they worked fine - resolution became good, etc. Then I accepted ubuntu's update prompt and on the next boot, after the boot splashscreen disappeared, the screen remained black. I tried pressing the hardware power button on the PC and that made the shutdown splashscreen visible; then the PC turned off.

I think the update messed up the graphic drivers somehow - maybe due to a kernel update which made the kernel incompatible with them.

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you install "the official GeForce drivers"? If you installed them from a file downloaded from Nvidia site, you will have to install them every time you update Linux kernel. It is a wrong way to install these drivers to Ubuntu.

Comment: If you installed using the Nvidia blob then you'll have to do it again each time the kernel is updated. Preferably uninstall those, reboot, open Additional Drivers and there select and apply the recommended Nvidia driver. Reboot. Properly installed and directly from the official repositories this driver will compile for the new kernels.

Comment: @Pilot6: That's exactly how I installed them. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Install them form Ubuntu repositories or a PPA. You can uninstall wrongly installed drivers from recovery console.

Comment: @Pilot6: I uninstalled them and did `sudo apt install nvidia-375`, works now. Thanks!